# Copy and paste a bunch of files with different name

Tags: command-line, text-processing, cp

I have a bunch of text files with the name

```
foo_bar_abc_1_01_geh_original.in
foo_bar_abc_1_02_geh_original.in
foo_bar_abc_1_03_geh_original.in
...
...
foo_bar_abc_1_1000_geh_original.in
```

I would like to *copy* (and keep the original files) each file and *paste* to different names (in the same folder) like,

```
foo_bar_abc_1_01_geh_copy.in
foo_bar_abc_1_02_geh_copy.in
foo_bar_abc_1_03_geh_copy.in
...
...
foo_bar_abc_1_1000_geh_copy.in
```

How can I do this using a simple script?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Change directory to where you have the original files.

Then test with the following command line,

```
for i in *_original.*;do echo cp -p "$i" "${i/_original./_copy.}";done
```

and if it looks good, remove `echo` and do the copying,

```
for i in *_original.*;do cp -p "$i" "${i/_original./_copy.}";done
```

Answer (score 8):

You can use `mcp` from the [`mmv` package[image: Install mmv]](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/mmv) in the following way:

```bsh
mcp "*original*" "#1copy#2"
```

This will copy every file containing the string “original” in the current directory and replace this string with “copy”. You can test what `mcp` will do by adding the `-n` flag, however it will not silently overwrite files, but ask you. Using `mmv` has the advantage over `cp` that you don’t have to call it for every single file – with one thousand files like you seem to copy, that makes a difference.

You could also use [GNU `parallel` [image: Install parallel]](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/parallel) in the following way (`--dry-run` is for testing, remove it to perform the copying):

```bsh
parallel --dry-run cp -p "{}" "{=s/original/copy/=}" ::: *
```

or, if that gives the “Argument list too long” error:

```bsh
printf "%s\0" * | parallel --dry-run -0 cp -p "{}" "{=s/original/copy/=}"
```

#### Example run

```bsh
$ ls -1
foo_bar_abc_1_01_geh_original.in
foo_bar_abc_1_02_geh_original.in
foo_bar_abc_1_03_geh_original.in
foo_bar_abc_1_04_geh_original.in
$ mcp "*original*" "#1copy#2"
$ ls -1
foo_bar_abc_1_01_geh_copy.in
foo_bar_abc_1_01_geh_original.in
foo_bar_abc_1_02_geh_copy.in
foo_bar_abc_1_02_geh_original.in
foo_bar_abc_1_03_geh_copy.in
foo_bar_abc_1_03_geh_original.in
foo_bar_abc_1_04_geh_copy.in
foo_bar_abc_1_04_geh_original.in
```

Let’s `time` it, run over 1000 files of 100 KiB each on a *slow* machine:

```bsh
$ time mcp "*original*" "#1copy#2"
real    0m1.114s
user    0m0.000s
sys     0m0.132s
```